# how to add 2 css widths from different classes

Tags: css

I have 2 classes.
class1
class2

class1 and class2 witdh is not fixed but responsive.

I would like to create a new class (name class3) whose width is combination of class1 and class2. something like below.

`class3 {witdh: class1 width + class2 width }

is this possible? and can it be achieved in CSS? or Jquery?

Thank you

Comment: How are they positioned in comparison to each other?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add two widths coming from two different classes, using css rules alone, but you may have the option to use custom properties to achieve that same result. You also have the option to get there using javascript but it would be an overkill if you have the chance to directly control your css rules like this instead:

```css
:root {
  --first-width: 20px;
  --second-width: 50px;
}

.class1{
  width: var(--first-width);  
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.class2{
  width: var(--second-width);
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.class3{
  width: calc( var(--first-width) + var(--second-width) );
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
class1
</div>
<div class="class2">
class2
</div>
<div class="class3">
class3
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! 
But what if we do not know the value of root? I mean it is not fixed value as it's responsively increasting and descreasing and even display:none when areas gets smaller..